# Partial application of MapThread

Tags: map

Suppose that I have

```
f[a_, b_, x_] := ...
```

I'd like to create a list of *n* pure functions

```
{f[1, 4, #]&, f[2, 5, #]&, f[3, 6, #]&, ...}
```

from two lists of length *n* like

```
as = {1, 2, 3, ...}
bs = {4, 5, 6, ...}
```

What can I do?

Given `g[a_, b_] = ...`, I know that to get `{g[1, 4], g[2, 5], g[3, 6], ...}` is to use `MapThread[g, {as, bs}]`, but I don't know how to extend this idea to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close to the solution.  You already have

```
as = {1, 2, 3}
bs = {4, 5, 6}

MapThread[g, {as, bs}]

(* ==> {g[1, 4], g[2, 5], g[3, 6]} *)
```

Now all you need is

```
g[a_, b_][x_] := f[a, b, x]
```

Or alternatively write `Function[{a, b}, f[a, b, #] &]` in place of `g` in `MapThread`.

Comment: Damn! you can't type so fast :)

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `With` to do it for you, `MapThread[With[{a = #1, b = #2}, f[a, b, #]&]&, {as, bs}]`

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
Transpose[{as, bs}] /. {a_, b_} :> (f[a, b, #] &)
(* {f[1, 4, #1] &, f[2, 5, #1] &, f[3, 6, #1] &} *)
```